# Django ImportError: No Module named apps when running on Openshift

Tags: django, openshift, importerror

Not sure what went wrong.  When I run on local machine using

```
 python manage.py runserver
```

all are ok.  But when running on Openshift, I got 500 Internal Server Error.

```
rhc tail -a maid
```

shows

```
==> app-root/logs/python.log <==
[Fri Mar 25 17:40:12 2016] [error] [client 127.3.227.129]   File "/var/lib/openshift/56f1365889f5cf9b07000054/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.2-py2.7.egg/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[Fri Mar 25 17:40:12 2016] [error] [client 127.3.227.129]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Fri Mar 25 17:40:12 2016] [error] [client 127.3.227.129]   File "/var/lib/openshift/56f1365889f5cf9b07000054/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.2-py2.7.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
[Fri Mar 25 17:40:12 2016] [error] [client 127.3.227.129]     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
[Fri Mar 25 17:40:12 2016] [error] [client 127.3.227.129]   File "/var/lib/openshift/56f1365889f5cf9b07000054/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.9.2-py2.7.egg/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
[Fri Mar 25 17:40:12 2016] [error] [client 127.3.227.129]     mod = import_module(mod_path)
[Fri Mar 25 17:40:12 2016] [error] [client 127.3.227.129]   File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Fri Mar 25 17:40:12 2016] [error] [client 127.3.227.129]     __import__(name)
[Fri Mar 25 17:40:12 2016] [error] [client 127.3.227.129] ImportError: No module named mblog.apps
82.28.196.48 - - [25/Mar/2016:13:40:11 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 617 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/601.4.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.3 Safari/601.4.4"
```

I already have mblog/**init**.py defines as

```
default_app_config = 'mblog.apps.MblogConfig'
```

and apps.py as

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.apps import AppConfig
class MblogConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'mblog'
    def ready(self):
        from .defaults import *
```

wsgi/application have following setting:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'], 'wsgi', 'MaidProject', 'mblog'))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'MaidProject.lineblog.settings'
```

The file structure is:

```
MaidProject
- __init__.py
- lineblog
  - __init__.py
  - settings.py
  - urls.py
  - wsgi.py
- manage.py
- mblog
  - __init__.py
  - admin.py
  - apps.py
  - default.py
  - ...
  - locale (dir)
  - templates (dir)
```

I don't get this issue when I push my previous Django 1.6 but now working on Django 1.9 with the new apps stuff.  Try a few things and get no where.  Any pointer is much appreciated.  The error is on Openshift but when run on local machine, there is no issue.  I must have done something wrong somewhere but spent a few days on it now and still get no where.  Really frustrated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try setting PYTHONPATH environment variable to include 'MaidProject' and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Graham for pointing out the PYTHONPATH.  That has fixed the issue.  It turns out that the path I set was incorrect and changing from

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'], 'wsgi', 'MaidProject', 'mblog'))
```

To the following has done the trick:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'], 'wsgi'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'], 'MaidProject'))
```